# Alerting user when div has been scrolled into view

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to perform a function/alert the user when they have scrolled down to a specific div, and then whey they have scrolled to the bottom of the page. I am able to alert when the user has scrolled to the bottom and back to the top, but not sure how to specify when the user scrolls below the fold(to the middle section). I have the following so far:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container top">TOP</div>
<div class="container middle">Middle</div>
<div class="container bottom">Bottom</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {
    var $win = $(window);

    $win.scroll(function () {
        if ($win.scrollTop() == 0) {
            alert("USER SCROLLED TO TOP");
        } else if ($win.height() + $win.scrollTop() == $(document).height()) {
            alert("USER SCROLLED TO BOTTOM");
        }
    });
});
```

**JSFIDDLE: [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/xsLx9ojs/3/)**

Comment: I usually use waypoints.js for this if you're open to using a library http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/

Comment: I have that as a backup, but shouldn't need to load a whole library for this one bit of functionality.

Comment: I created a fiddle using that plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/xv4z4krm/, but how can I prevent the alert from being triggered when I scroll back up?

Comment: I agree it shouldn't require a full library, but you can manually disable that waypoint after triggering it http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/api/disable/ and reenable it when needed.

Comment: No need for plugins. Wouldn't wanna waste a working example. http://jsfiddle.net/h49yd8wg/

Comment: @Shikkediel - your fiddle is closer. Knowing when the user scrolls to the top is not needed. I need to be able to know when they scroll to the bottom div, and then another when they scroll to the bottom of the page.

Comment: This of any help? http://jsfiddle.net/mL8nqgb4/

Comment: @Shikkediel - Just about. I would need it to work with a similar layout to this: http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/mL8nqgb4/1/, where once you hit the bottom of the gray "top" section, it fires an alert letting you know that you've gone below the "fold" of the page. Then another alert once the footer section has come into view.

Comment: Not seeing the difference. Please be more specific in your original question then.

Comment: The "scrolling the footer" message doesn't appear until you hit the footer. I need to be able to alert the user when the section below the gray "top" section comes into the viewport, and then another alert when the footer is in view. So instead of the "scrolling the footer" function, I need to be able to know when the user hits the white "Bottom" section.

Comment: It should function similar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/t8qyekzb/, but instead of being a div in a div, it should work with the layout of: http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/mL8nqgb4/1/

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/xsLx9ojs/1/

I add ids to the html divs:

```
<div id="top" class="container top">TOP</div>
<div id="bottom" class="container bottom">BOTTOM</div>
```

Then I add a condition to detect when bottom div appears in user's screen when he scrolls:

```
$(function () {

      var $win = $(window);

      $win.scroll(function () {
          if ($win.scrollTop() == 0) {
              console.log("USER SCROLLED TO TOP");
          } else if ($win.height() + $win.scrollTop() >= $('#top').height() - 50 
                    && $win.height() + $win.scrollTop() <= $('#top').height() + 50) {
              console.log("TRANSITION BETWEEN THE TWO DIVS");
          } else if ($win.height() + $win.scrollTop() == $(document).height()) {
              console.log("USER SCROLLED TO BOTTOM");
          }
      });

  });
```

Scroll detection is not so precise cause of the little "jumps" that the mousewheel does. So I added a 100px tolerance. If I were you I would improve this stuff with a boolean that detects if the alert for bottom div has already been given or not so the function doesn't trigger at every scroll like this:

```
    [...]
    if ($win.scrollTop() == 0) {
        //top reached
    } else if ($win.height() + $win.scrollTop() >= $('#top').height()) {
        //alert! bottom div appeared while scrolling bottom!
        //deal with this with a boolean
    } else if ($win.scrollTop() <= $('#top').height()) {
        //alert! bottom div disappeared while scrolling top!
        //deal with this with a boolean
    } else if ($win.height() + $win.scrollTop() == $(document).height()) {
        //bottom reached
    }
    [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of the issue is that the value of `$(document).height()` may never be obtained via scrolling, as elements within the page can affect the actual document height versus what the user is able to scroll through.

You could find the position of the bottom container like so

`$('.bottom').position();`

But that would only give you the element's position within its parent. You would then need to calculate the offset relative to each parent and grandparent, where applicable.

Likewise, you could look into the [getBoundingClientRect function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect):

```
$('.bottom')[0].getBoundingClientRect();
```

Take a look at the library [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) to see a "ready-made" version.

**Update 1**:
For your JSFiddle sample, keep in mind that Waypoints needs to have an element hit the top of the window to trigger (this is by default - you can adjust this behavior with an `offset`).

[See my JSFiddle here where](http://jsfiddle.net/q9e3wa73/4/) I've made each div larger to allow the window to scroll passed, based on your JSFiddle.

Comment: I've setup a demo, but it isn't triggering when the middle element comes into view: http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/ea7stw0f/3/